# LaTeX Centering newline in subfloat caption

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, captions, subfloats

I have these images with their title beneath: [image]

I want to add some information below, like this: [image: desc]

```
\subfloat[Highway\\1700 frames\\800x600]{\includegraphics{highway.jpg}}
or
\subfloat[\shortstack{Office\\2050 frames\\800x600}]{\includegraphics{office.jpg}}
```

The simple slash `\\` solution stop working (shift to the left) when there's too much text. The `\shortstack` solution always work, but there's not a lot of space between the lines.

The problem is, even when they work, both give me the following errors :

```
There were errors in your LaTeX source
test.tex:22: Argument of \sf@@@subfloat has an extra }. [...e=0.9]{highway.jpg}}]
test.tex:22: Paragraph ended before \sf@@@subfloat was complete. [...e=0.9]{highway.jpg}}]
```

Is there any way to do what I want?

Here's a working minimal exemple :

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht] \centering
    \subfloat[Highway]{\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{highway.jpg}} ~
    \subfloat[Office]{\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{office.jpg}} ~
    \subfloat[Pedestrians]{\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{pedestrians.jpg}} ~

    \caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE:**
The good news is, I am able to do it. The last screenshot is from my PDF previewer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `\subfloat` macro of [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) provides two different optional arguments:

```
\subfloat[<LoF entry>][<caption entry>]{<stuff>}
```

The above stems from the [`subfig` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf) (p 4, section **2.2.1 The `\subﬂoat` Command**):

[image]

Since line breaking in the LoF (or any "List of" or "Table of" structure) is not wanted and problematic, use something like this:

```
\subfloat[Highway, 1700 frames, 800x600][Highway\\1700 frames\\800x600]{\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{highway.jpg}}
```

This separates the floatable (fragile) content (destined for the LoF) from the typesetting content.

Comment: Using the List.Entry optional argument removes the errors. Thanks. It doesn't work with \\ though. The text goes to the left when I have more than two lines, or if I remove a word ...? It appears to be random! But it works with \shortstack. Thanks.

Comment: @Nil: In my examples it works. Otherwise try `\centering Highway\par 1700 frames\par 800x600`. My version of [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) is `2005/06/28 ver: 1.3` (from TeX Live 2011).

Comment: `\centering ...\par` worked for me :)